# Can't save ForeignKey data with Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a way to log notes associated with records. When the form is submitted, it's trying to redirect to the same url, but without the record id, which should be required to view the page. I defined it in urls with the record id, so it should be tracker/19/newnote

I want it to route to tracker/19/detail, and I'm not sure why it's routing to tracker/newnote, which doesn't exist in my urls file. Maybe I need to create it?

anyway, here are my files if anyone wants to take a crack at this with me.

**models.py**

```
class Record(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField('Serial Number', max_length=9)
    product = models.CharField('Product', max_length=6)
    ticket = models.CharField('Log/RID', max_length=9)
    eng_date = models.DateField('Date Engaged')
    customer = models.CharField('Customer', max_length=80)
    details = models.TextField('Problem Details', max_length=800)
    owner = models.CharField('Owner', max_length=40)

class Note(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note_text = models.TextField('Notes', max_length=2000)
    note_date = models.DateField('Date Entered')
```

**views.py**

```
def newnote(request, record_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            r = Record.objects.get(pk=record_id)
            r.note_set.create(note_text=form.note_text, note_date=form.note_date)
            r.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tracker/%s/detail/' % record_id)
    else:
        form = NoteForm()
    return render(request, 'tracker/noteform.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields = ['note_text',
                  'note_date'
                 ]
        widgets = {
                'note_date': DateInput(),}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
    path('<int:record_id>/detail/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('result/', views.result, name='result'),
    path('query/', views.query, name='query'),
    path('all/', views.show_all, name='all'),
    path('<int:record_id>/newnote/', views.newnote, name='newnote'),
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**nameform.html** template

```
<div id=form>
<h3>New Note??</h3>
<hr>
<form action="/tracker/newnote/" method="post">  
    <div id="fields">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Note:<br>{{ form.note_text }}</p>
    <p>Note Date:<br>{{ form.note_date }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This might not be core issue, but `form.note_text` does not contain the data you want to save, that would be `form.cleaned_data['note_text']`. There is also no need to save the record after creating a note instance.

Comment: Please show your template - what URL is the form posting to?

Comment: Just added the template, and it is indeed posting to /tracker/newnote/, so I'm guessing that would be a problem. I'm kind of new at this, so I'm not sure where I sould need to direct the post.

edit: I would like it to go to the detail page after, e.g.: /tracker/19/detail/

Comment: Usually you just post it back to the same place, ie `action="."`.

Comment: Daniel! That worked! I also added the cleaned_data as schwobaseggl recommended, and now it works how I want it to. Thanks for all your help today